# Can I force Azure API Management to return 400 instead of 404 when missing required field?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

We have an application that requires some fields to be present. If those fields aren't present we will return a 400 response explaining what is missing in a proper error message. Adding APIM to the mix complicates it a lot it seems. Since APIM know that the field is required it looks like it will short curcuit and return 404 with a generic message instead of our self explanatory message of what is wrong.

Is it a way to turn of this functionality for APIM?

Comment: By field, do you mean query parameters?

Comment: yes. We have some fields that are required. I do understand that APIM is doing something by its best intention, but I would rather control the error message here.

Comment: I don't think it will response 404 if missing fields in  query parameters. 404 error can just be response when you request an incorrect url. Could you please provide a sample of your backend url and also a sample of your APIM api ?

Comment: But that is the thing. Since we have the query params as required apim will short circuit the request with a 404 if required parameter is missing and return 404 instead of letting the query through to the app. So maybe it’s the wrong description.

Comment: I hit this issue myself. I found that APIM is importing my required query parameters as template parameters, which causes the URL matching to fail when the query isn't provided.

However, it's possible to edit the endpoints after importing them from an OpenAPI spec. I was able to remove the template parameter and add a required query parameter, which works as expected.

See my question at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/829259/apim-returning-404-when-mandatory-query-parameter.html?childToView=835461#answer-835461

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting the same issue and I endup changing my approach. What I did was to configure it on the Application side and use FluentValidation to make the querystring parameters required. So, my model now looks something like this:

```cs
using FluentValidation;

public class UrlQueryParameters
{
    public string PropertyA { get; set; }
    public string PropertyB { get; set; }
}

public class UrlQueryParametersValidator : AbstractValidator<UrlQueryParameters>
{
    public UrlQueryParametersValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(o => o.PropertyA)
            .NotEmpty()
            .WithMessage("The 'PropertyA' parameter was missing or a value was not provided.");

        RuleFor(o => o.PropertyB)
            .NotEmpty()
            .WithMessage("The 'PropertyB' parameter was missing or a value was not provided.");
    }
}
```

The preceding code defines a couple of validation rules with custom messages for `PropertyA` and `PropertyB` properties.

Now, enable FluentValidation as the default validation mechanism for our application by adding the following code at `ConfigureServices` method of `Startup.cs` file:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    // Rest of the code omitted for brevity
    
    services
      .AddControllers()
      .AddFluentValidation(fv => 
      { 
          fv.DisableDataAnnotationsValidation = true;
          
          // The following line registers ALL public validators in the assembly containing UrlQueryParametersValidator
          // There is no need to register additional validators from this assembly.
          fv.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<UrlQueryParametersValidator>(lifetime: ServiceLifetime.Singleton);
      });
}
```

At this point, your API endpoints should validate the required parameters from the request and APIM should not short-circuit the request by throwing `404 Not Found` when you try to access `/api/foo/{id}`.

The reason why this works because Swashbuckle doesn't automatically import validation rules from FluentValidation. Meaning, the properties `PropertyA` and `PropertyB` won't be marked as required when viewing them in the Swagger UI. This is the downside for this approach as the required querystring parameters from the Swagger UI will not be marked as required which could be confusing to consumers. But to me, returning the correct StatusCode with meaningful message to consumers is more important and that's why I will stick to this workaround for the time being. You could try using the `MicroElements.Swashbuckle.FluentValidation` to altleast set/marked the parameters as required in the Swagger UI schema. But that's just about it.

I blogged about this it here: [Dirty Hack on Making the Required QueryString Params to Work in Azure APIM](https://vmsdurano.com/dirty-hack-on-making-the-required-querystring-params-to-work-in-azure-apim/)

Answer (score 0):

At API/Product/Global level policy add on-error section, use choose policy to check if operation was found or not:

```
<choose>
  <when condition="@(context.LastError.Source == "configuration" && context.LastError.Reason == "OperationNotFound")">
    <return-response>
      <set-status code="400" reason="Bad Request" />
    </return-response>
  </when>
</choose>
```

Comment: Thanks, but maybe I should elaborate on what I mean. It seems like APIM "hijacks" the request and return 404 before even calling the backend since it can't match to the operation. This was not the behavior I expected.

Comment: Then you should mark those query parameters as not required. Then APIM will match operation with and without query parameters.

Comment: I don’t think that is the answer. I want the spec to generate the as required so you can read the open api spec and see what you must provide. I also want to return good error messages if someone doesn’t follow the spec, and that isn’t possible the way apim behaves.